# SQL Where condition for number of years

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare int @NumberofPriorYears=2;
Declare int @currentYear=2014;

SELECT
 *
FROM
MyTable a
WHERE
a.FiscalYear in (
```

When @NumberofPriorYears is 2 then i want to pass `@currentYear-@NumberofPriorYears` (i.e 2014,2013,2012) 
or when `@NumberofPriorYears` is null then pass `@currentYear` i.e 2014.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a range?

```
a.FiscalYear >= @currentYear-isnull(@NumberofPriorYears,0)
and a.FiscalYear < @currentYear+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Declare int @numberofyears=2;
Declare int @currentYear=2014;

set @currentYear = datepart(year,getdate())


SELECT
 *
FROM
MyTable a
WHERE
datepart(year,a.FiscalYear) between @currentYear and @currentYear+@numberofYears
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable a
WHERE @currentYear - a.FiscalYear <= ISNULL(@numberOfPriorYears, 0)
```

If you want to be able to pass in a previous year instead of just the current year (e.g. see 2011-2012 instead of 2011-2014) you can use `BETWEEN`

```
WHERE a.FiscalYear BETWEEN @currentYear - ISNULL(@numberOfPriorYears, 0) AND @currentYear
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare int @numberofyears=2;
Declare int @currentYear=2014;

SELECT *
FROM  MyTable a
WHERE
    ( YEAR(a.FiscalYear) >= YEAR(GETDATE()) -  @numberofyears
      AND 
      @numberofyears IS NOT NULL
    )
OR
 ( YEAR(a.FiscalYear) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND 
    @numberofyears IS NULL
  )
```